# Regex, two uppercase characters in a string

Tags: regex

I'd like to use Regex to ensure that there are **at least two upper case characters** in a string, in any position, together or not.

The following gives me two together:

```
([A-Z]){2}
```

Environment - Classic ASP VB.

Comment: The simple answer: `[A-Z].*[A-Z]`. [Illustrated here](https://regex101.com/r/KmQnrE/1)

Comment: That works, thanks for your help. Although this a comment, not an answer so I cannot mark it as a solution. Shall I mark the one below as the solution? Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the simple regex

```
[A-Z].*[A-Z]
```

which matches an upper case letter, followed by any number of anything (except linefeed), and another uppercase letter.

If you need it to allow linefeeds between the letters, you'll have to set the *single line* flag. If you're using JavaScript (U should always include flavor/language-tag when asking regex-related questions), it doesn't have that possibility. Then the solution suggested by Wiktor S in a comment to another answer should work.

Answer (score 3):

`[A-Z].*[A-Z]`

A to Z , any symbols between, again A to Z

**update**

As  Wiktor mentioned in comments:

> This regex will check for 2 letters on a line (in most regex flavors), not in a string.

So

`[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]`

Should do the thing (In most  regex flavors/tools)

Comment: This regex will check for 2 letters on a *line* (in most regex flavors), not in a *string*.

Comment: .*([A-Z]).*([A-Z]).* then?

Comment: No, `[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]`. And only if partial matching is possible. And even this expression might fail in some flavors/tools. The question lacks an important detail: where the regex is used.

Comment: He said, he was using ASP VB

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is something like this:

```
.*([A-Z]).*([A-Z]).*
```

Broken out into segments thats:

```
.*        //Any number of characters (including zero)
([A-Z])   //A capital letter
.*        //Any number of characters (including zero)
([A-Z])   //A second capital letter
.*        //Any number of characters (including zero)
```

Comment: .* is redundant on sides

Comment: Wouldn't it just match the capitals and the characters between them without that (eg: http://www.regextester.com/?fam=97470)? If OP wants it to match the whole string, I'd generally include them, though I'm not familiar with ASP VB, so I could be wrong for this use case.